# Many to Many with HasMany

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, relationship

Is there way to chain ManytoMany queries with hasMany?
Thanks

```
     $user=User::find(Auth::Id());
        $pagination=$user->emails()->where('email.draft','<>',true)->
        where('email.trash','<>',true)->
        orderby('date_time','desc')->paginate(10);
        foreach ($pagination as $email)
        {
            echo $email->pivot->sender_UID;//sender_UID references users table
            echo $email->message;
        }
```

The above query hasn Many to many relationship and works fine but I want to bind the hasMany relationship result with the same query. E.x sender_UID has Many to one relationship with users table so I want the query to also grab the f_name and l_name of the user with corresponding sender_UID So the foreach would printing something look like this..

```
        foreach ($pagination as $email)
        {
            echo $email->f_name;
            echo $email->message;
        }
```

[PhpmyAdmin DB designer](http://s23.postimg.org/cohehvs57/tables.png)

```
    //User Model
   class User extends Eloquent {
     public function emails()
     {  
        return $this->belongsToMany('Email', 'users_email', 'Uid','email_id')->
        withPivot('sender_UID');
     }
     public function userinfo()
      {
         return $this->hasMany('User_email','sender_UID');
      }
    }
  // Email Model
  class Email extends Eloquent
    {
      public function attach()
      {
          return $this->hasMany('Attachments','email_id');
      }
      public function users()
      { 
          return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'users_email', 'email_id','Uid');
      }
    }
 //User_Email Model
  class User_email extends Eloquent
    {
      protected $table="users_Email";
      protected $primaryKey="Id";
      public function senderinfo()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo('User','Id','sender_UID');
     }
   }

}
```